# How would I detect fiddler running?

Tags: visual-c++

(I need this code for microsoft visual studio 2015 C++ projects)

I'm trying to detect when this application is running:
https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

I tried to use FindWindow and FindWindowEx microsoft functions to detect the process when its running which both have failed to do so.

Example code I tried:

```
#include "Windows.h"
if (FindWindow(0, "Fiddler") != NULL){
//window was found
}
else{
//window not found
}
```

however even though the process running is named "Fiddler" it stills seems to go undetected by FindWindow even though FindWindow finds things such as notepad.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindWindow returns a window handle if the window classname or window name matches the specified string. A window name is not the same as a process name. See here how to address your problem using the Process32First/Process32Next API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701(v=vs.85).aspx